# Combine FileType with other events

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I'd like to combine two events: `FileType` and `TextChangedI`. According to [this awesome book](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html#multiple-events) I can do that, by adding a comma between both events like this:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre,BufRead *.html :normal gg=G
```

But if I try that with `FileType` and `TextChangedI` like that:

```
autocmd TextChangedI,FileType c echom "Test"
```

then I don't get any output if I change something in a `c` file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `TextChangedI` matches against the filename, and `FileType` against the filetype, you can't really combine those two. `<buffer>` is a special pattern which matches against the current buffer.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you for the information! Do you have an idea for a workaround for this "combination"? One idea would be that the user has to provide something like a whitelist and the plugin iterates everytime through that list, but it might has a pretty bad performance...

Comment: I would just define two autocmds and put the actual code in a function.

Comment: We do prefer multiple questions to be split up; I’ve been personally lenient with this when the questions are intricately connected (splitting is not always easy!), but that doesn’t seem to be the case here. I *believe* your questions are (1) why doesn’t this combined autocommand work (and how do i fix it), and (2) what’s this `<buffer>` stuff?  I’ve removed the second question. You should feel free to post it separately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin mentions in the comments, the two events match on different things. It would be simpler to make a function and use two autocommands (the combined form works best when both match on the same types of things):

```
function DoIt() abort
endfunction

augroup my_c_stuff
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType c call DoIt()
  autocmd TextChangedI *.c call DoIt()
augroup END
```

An even better solution would be to put the function, call, and text-changed autocommand into an ftplugin:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim
function DoIt() abort
endfunction

call DoIt()

augroup my_c_stuff
  autocmd! * <buffer>
  autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> call DoIt<()
augroup END
" don’t forget b:undo_ftplugin!
```

Comment: What do you mean with `" don’t forget b:undo_ftplugin!`?

Comment: @TornaxO7 see the help on the subject. It’s a variable containing a string of code that runs to “destruct” all the filetype-specific code when a buffer’s filetype changes. If you change filetypes, you don’t want the old stuff lingering around!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Would be nice if you could explain the code.